# Element is not Attached to the DOM in Playwright Python

Tags: python, browser-automation, playwright-python

When I run this code, it opens chrome, goes to the link, loads data and then clicks on load more. When all the data is loaded, and the load more button disappears, it gives me the error that Element is not attached to DOM. Why?

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time
import csv


# Main Function
        while True:
            load_more_button = page.query_selector('.link-underline.text-xl')
            if load_more_button:
                #getting error here
                load_more_button.click()
            else:
                print("clicked")`your text`
                break

        # Now Find the Links on the Page
        links = page.query_selector_all("a[class*='algolia-hit-link']")
        count = 1
        for link in links:
            link = "https://luxuryrehabs.com" + link.get_attribute("href")
            output_result = [link]
            write_to_file([output_result])
            original_list.append(link)
            print(f"{count}: {link}")
            count += 1
```

The code works fine until the load more button disappears. When all the data loaded, then I get this error `Element is not attached to DOM`.

Comment: Use locators instead of query_selector

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. What are you trying to accomplish on the site, exactly?

Comment: this code is used to get url from the link

Comment: Share the URL, otherwise it is very difficult to help you

Comment: Thanks Sir, Problem was solved, the problem was related to button,  the way i was using the class to click the button was wrong